# How to create a function that returns a list that is a union of the elements of a nested list in Ocaml?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

If I was given a set of lists within a list in Ocaml, for example [[3;1;3]; [4]; [1;2;3]], then how can we implement a function to return a list that is a union of the values of the nested list (so the output from the example will return [1;2;3;4])? I tried removing duplicates from the list, but it didn't work as intended. I am also restricted to using the List module only.

Comment: Why didn't the removing duplicates thing worked? Can you share your tries because otherwise noone will answer in order to not do your homeworks for you if you didn't put an effort

Answer (score 2):

Restricted to using the `List` module only? Sounds like homework with an arbitrary limit like that. so I don't want to give a fully working solution. However, if you look through the [`List`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/api/List.html) documentation, you'll see a couple of functions that can be combined to do what you want.

[`concat`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/api/List.html#VALconcat), which takes a list of lists and flattens them out into a single list, and [`sort_uniq`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.12/api/List.html#VALsort_uniq), which sorts a list and removes duplicates.

So you just have to take your list of lists, turn it into a single list, and `sort_uniq` that (With an appropriate comparison function) to get your desired results.